# PHP curl post call is not working, rather it's redirecting to login page

Tags: php, curl

Trying to call a java service from php client using curl function. My api expecting a json request body like below,

```
 {"personRequest":{"emailId":"rupanjan@gmail.com","isActive":"true"}}
```

And my php client code as follows,

```
    $postData['personRequest'] = array(
        'emailId' => $emailId,
        'isActive' => "true"
    );


    //$data = Array();
    //$data['personRequest']['isActive'] = "true";
    //$postFields = json_encode($data);

    $postFields = json_encode($postData);

    $url = "$server_url" . "service/membership/update";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postFields))
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $ch;
    print_r($result);
```

after execution it's showing a blank response, I have access to server code also, tried to put a debug point in my java code, seems http call didn't reach my server at all..

just now executed var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
got below output,
array(22) { ["url"]=> string(66) "http://9splatform.com/sample-server/service/membership/update" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(302) ["header_size"]=> int(306) ["request_size"]=> int(215) ["filetime"]=> int(-1) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0) ["total_time"]=> float(0.004441) ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.000245) ["connect_time"]=> float(0.000705) ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.000714) ["size_upload"]=> float(65) ["size_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_download"]=> float(0) ["speed_upload"]=> float(14636) ["download_content_length"]=> float(0) ["upload_content_length"]=> float(65) ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.004389) ["redirect_time"]=> float(0) ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } ["redirect_url"]=> string(95) "http://9splatform.com/sample-server/login.html;jsessionid=A32AF520FE766BB5D444823D1419F4M9" }

that means this is redirecting to login page, can anybody please help me ... i have no clue why it's happening ...

Comment: Try adding a `var_dump(curl_error($ch));` after your `curl_exec` statement to see if you are getting any cURL errors ...

Comment: Also, are you sure that `$server_url` contains the correct information? You don't need to wrap `$server_url` in double quotes ... it's better to write: `$url = $server_url . 'service/membership/update';`

Comment: It looks like you need to login prior to posting to the `service/membership/update` page ... you will need to login via cURL, store the cookie, the use the stored cookie for your subsequent call.

Comment: @dleiftah .. thank for your help ... tried with '        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);' ... it's now giving the login page itself... any suggestion .. please

Comment: see my last comment ... you will need to login via curl to authenticate the call. Is the Java service set up to be called from a script? If it's something that's allowed, they should provide an API that doesn't require doing a login auth and using cookies (i.e., they would expose an API)

Comment: @dleiftah .. thanks again, let me check my server code, will update the post soon ...have a nice day ahead.

Comment: @dleiftah .. thanks alot for you support .. I have fixed it .. answer I have posted as a new entry ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` instead of `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`

### If the above doesn't work, do exactly like this

```
<?php
    $postData['personRequest'] = array(
        'emailId'=>"rupanjan@gmail.com",
        'isActive' => "true"
    );

    $postFields = json_encode($postData['personRequest']); /JSON encoding the array

    $url = "$server_url" . "service/membership/update";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Removed the header... 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shankar for your kind response. I am new to php.
Tried with the same piece of code you given in my apps, it's exactly the same, '$result' is empty. And tried doing 'echo $ch;' .. it prints 'Resource id #38'. No clue ...

Comment: @Shankar... can you please help me out ... my entire portal is stuck for this post call implementation ...

Answer (score 0):

```
in LOGIN page
================

$url = $server_url . "login.html";
        $postdata = http_build_query(array(
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password
                ));

        $tmp_fname = tempnam("/tmp", "COOKIE");
        $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $tmp_fname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept: application/json')
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


in SUBSEQUENT requests
===========================

I have to add the cookies for every protected resource call...

$id = $this->input->post('id');
        $emailId = $this->input->post('emailId');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $tmp_fname = $this->session->userdata('cookies_file');
        $userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6";

        $personObj['personRequest'] = array(
            'emailId' => $emailId,
            'isActive' => "true"
        );

        $postdata = json_encode($personObj);


        $url = $server_url . 'service/membership/update';
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $tmp_fname);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Accept: application/json')
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```